# Cancel event handler using webgrid in MVC asp net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I have a problem when I try to cancel event handler using webgrid in MVC asp net C#.

This is my code

```
//Cancel event handler.
$("body").on("click", "#WebGrid TBODY .Cancel", function () {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    $("td", row).each(function () {
        if ($(this).find(".text").length > 0) {
            var span = $(this).find(".label2");
            var input = $(this).find(".text");
            input.val(span.html());
            span.show();
            input.hide();
        }
    });
    row.find(".Edit").show();
    row.find(".Update").hide();
    $(this).hide();
});

webGrid.Column(header: "day_gv",
style: "day_gv",
format: @<span>
<span class="label2">@item.day_gv</span>@if (@item.Truefalse)
{<span><input class="text" type="text" value="0000-00-00" style="display:none" disabled /></span>}
else
{<span><input class="text" type="text" value="@item.day_gv" style="display:none" /></span>}
</span>)

webGrid.Column(header: "day_hh",
style: "day_hh",
format: @<span>
<span class="label2">@item.day_hh</span>@if (@item.Truefalse)
{<span><input class="text" type="text" value="0000-00-00" style="display:none" disabled /></span>}
else
{<span><input class="text" type="text" value="@item.day_hh" style="display:none" /></span>}
</span>)
```

If editing the row where the value of `@item.Truefalse` is true

[image]

the return on webgrid is

[image]

If try cancel editing on the same row of `@item.Truefalse` is true and try to re-open EDIT, the return is empty

[image]

The problem it's if cancel editing and re-open EDIT on the same row , webgrid don't showing the values as the image number two inserted on this question and show empties input text on new editing as the image number three inserted on this question.

How to do resolve this?

Comment: You can try in the end `return false;` inside cancel javascript method. This will stop the event bubbling.

Comment: @Arshad I'm sorry... not understand your suggestion

Comment: If you cancel edit, and reopen EDIT, what should it show? Basically you have not told us what the issue is.

Comment: @CodingYoshi the problem it's if cancel editing and re-open EDIT on the same row , webgrid don't showing the values as the image number two inserted on this question and show empties input text on new editing as the image number three inserted on this question

Comment: Check the value of `span.html()` because I don't think that's what you want to do. This line may be the issue: `input.val(span.html());`